# Removing spaces from a string, SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm trying to write a SQL query that will remove all spaces so that if a string only has spaces the final string is just ''.

I've tried this code but apparently it isn't working for more than one space:

```
regexp_replace(:P14_search_text, '( ){1,}', '')
```

Being :`P14_search_text` the string I want to modify.

Any help?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

how about:

```
regexp_replace(:P14_search_text, '[[:space:]]*', '');
```

Comment: It didn't work either :/ I'm starting to think the problem is in my code but I just can't find the flaw...thank you anyway (:

Answer (score 5):

try this:

```
     Select Replace(:P14_search_text, ' ', '');
```

Comment: so, what did you get from that?

Comment: I'm applying this on a search text box, so when I type just one space, it's good, but whenever I type in more than one space, it doesn't work.

Answer (score 3):

Hope this helps you,

```
SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE(' Any  String ','( ){1,}','') "REGEXP_REPLACE"  FROM DUAL;
SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE('  ','( ){1,}','') "REGEXP_REPLACE"  FROM DUAL;
```

Answer (score 3):

I tried the same method as @Don suggested and it works in oracle 10 xe.

```
select replace('     lkjds  d   s   adkj      ', ' ', '') from dual
```

result

```
lkjdsdsadkj
```

Answer (score 2):

the following query works for me in oracle:

```
select
    :tst_val AS INPUT,
    regexp_replace(:tst_val, '[[:space:]]*', '') AS MODIFIED
from
    dual
```

if this query does not work for you, would you show us what results you're getting?

Comment: It's not working, this is what I'm trying to accomplish:




where
bobooks.owner <> :app_user
and
(:P14_search_text IS NULL
or
regexp_replace(:P14_search_text, '[[:space:]]*', '') = ''
or
((lower(:P14_CATEGORY) <> 'title' or (lower(:P14_CATEGORY) = 'title' and lower(bobooks.title) like '%' || lower(:P14_search_text) || '%'))
and
(lower(:P14_CATEGORY) <> 'author' or (lower(:P14_CATEGORY) = 'author' and lower(bobooks.author) like '%' || lower(:P14_search_text) || '%'))))

Comment: are you in a sql server database or an oracle database?

Comment: is the query just not returning anything or is it giving you an error? and what about the query in my answer?  what does it return?

Comment: It's not returning anything, it's working as if it only changes 1 space, after two spaces I receive nothing, no data, on the other hand when I type in just one space, I receive all available data, just as planned, yoour query does the same

Comment: try changing the expression to `regexp_replace(:P14_search_text, '[[:space:]]*', '', 1, 0)` to explicitly tell it to replace all occurences.  it should do this by default, but apparently is not.

Comment: how about trying `(SELECT regexp_replace(:P14_search_text, '[[:space:]]*', '') FROM DUAL) = ''`